# Ultegra 6800 chainrings and Claris r2000

Tags: shimano, crankset, chainring

Does claris R2000 crank arms can fit ultegra 6800 chainrings?

Answer (score 1):

Claris - https://bike.shimano.com/en-US/product/component/claris-r2000/FC-R2000.html

Ultegra - https://bike.shimano.com/en-US/product/component/ultegra-6800/FC-6800.html

They have the same PCD and chain line which are the two measurements that show you whether the chainrings will sit correctly. I would be surprised if they weren't compatible based on this but I'm not 100% sure they are so take this with a grain of salt. Their Q-factors are different but I doubt most people would notice 3.4mm difference.

Comment: Take a closer look at the branches. The Ultegra are thinner. There will be a step if you cross-fit them

Comment: @Carel yes but they will likely fit, I think OP realizes that they won't match aesthetically